# Realm: Inserting RealmObject with references to other objects of the same type

Tags: java, android, realm

I'm trying to insert an Object that has a reference to objects of the same type (which also do not exist in the database, yet):

```
@RealmClass
public class User extends RealmObject implements RealmObjectModel, Serializable
{
    @PrimaryKey
    private long id;

    private RealmList<User> friends = new RealmList<>();
    private RealmList<User> sentFriendRequests = new RealmList<>();

    //getter, setter, other stuff
}
```

but everytime I insert or copy the root object, realm only saves one object and it's not root, but apparently the last object it can find, in this case the object in sentFriendRequests. What is happening? Why doesn't it save every object to the database?

```
public static void insertOrUpdate(final User user)
{
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction()
    {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm)
        {
            realm.insertOrUpdate(user);
        }
    });

    realm.close();
}
```

Apparently realm cannot handle multi-insertion via RealmLists, so I'll probably have to insert every object by itself. Quite honestly more work than it should be.

Comment: Can you show the code you use to insert data?

Comment: updated the post to include the insert code. As I wrote, I think it's a bummer that realm won't insert sub-objects recursively. I understand it's because of the missing auto-increment, but that feature should be a must-have.